# Why am I getting this "Help on Response in module requests.models object:" screen?

Tags: python, google-vision

I'm learning google vision and I have an app that's been working as expected. All of a sudden when I go to execute the python script, I get this window:

[image: screen shot]

I have to press 'q' in terminal to quit this "help screen" before my code continues. I'm unsure where and why this started popping up. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: most probably you run the script with some exra parameter (possibly a typo) like `-h`

Comment: I wish it were that simple. I made a completely new script with only the import statements along with the Google Application Credentials, and client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(). Nothing else is in the file. And that screen still pops up.

Comment: I mean you call the command-line script with some extra parameter. Please post the exact shell command you use to run the script

Comment: python visionapi.py

Comment: can you post the python code of the script?

Comment: I just tried a number of different scripts this morning, all having to do with google vision, and that screen isn't showing anymore. No idea what happened. Nothing changed.